# Customization of middle axis lines

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to customize a bit the axis lines extension of `pgfplots`. Here is my code and what I get now.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
  compat = 1.7,
  every non boxed x axis/.style = {%
    enlarge x limits = true,
    x axis line style = {-stealth}
  },
  every non boxed y axis/.style = {%
    enlarge y limits = true,
    y axis line style = {-stealth}
  },
  axis x line = middle,
  axis y line = middle,
  every axis x label/.style = {%
    at = {(xticklabel cs:1)},
    anchor = north},
  every axis y label/.style = {%
    at = {(yticklabel cs:1)},
    anchor=east}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xlabel = $x$, 
               ylabel = $\sin x$]
    \addplot+[domain=-10:.5,samples=40] {sin(deg(x))+2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to do four things automatically and I'm struggling with the doc...

1. Both axis must intersect at `(0,0)` whatever the function ploted is.
2. The `xlabel` must be below the `xaxis` at its end and the `ylabel` at left of the `yaxis` at its end (similar to the ticklabels).
3. I want the `ticklabel` `0` to appear below left `(0,0)` once (say only as a `xticklabel`).
4. Whatever the function ploted is, I'd like the axis to intersect at `(0,0)` and go at least a bit in the four directions (up, down, left and right, like a `+`). In the example above, I only get a `_|_`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Add `before end axis/.code={\addplot [draw=none, forget plot] coordinates {(0,0)};}` to your options. This will add an invisible plot with one coordinate at the origin that makes sure that the origin is always included.
2. Use `xlabel style={anchor=north}, ylabel style={anchor=east}`. When using `axis lines=middle`, the labels are automatically positioned at the tips of the axes, only with a different alignment to the one you're requesting.
3. You could add `\node at (axis cs:0,0) [anchor=north east] {0};` to the `before end axis/.code` options. This will give you a slightly different alignment compared to the x tick labels, which may or may not be desirable.
4. Add `enlargelimits=true`. In conjunction with point 1, this will make sure the axis always extends at least a little bit past the origin:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
  compat = 1.7,
  axis lines=middle,
  enlargelimits=true,
  before end axis/.code={
    \addplot [draw=none, forget plot] coordinates {(0,0)};
    \node at (axis cs:0,0) [anchor=north east] {0};
  },
  xlabel style={
    anchor=north
  },
  ylabel style={
    anchor=east
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xlabel = $x$, 
               ylabel = $\sin x$]
    \addplot+[domain=-10:.5,samples=40] {sin(deg(x))+2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks! Works like a charm. Point 1 is very clever `:)`.